cookies disappear in production build but works fine in development mode (mern app)
I have been following (this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAaUy_Moivw&t=3908s) tutorial on building a real estate marketplace using MERN. Here are the relevant codes from the tutorial (https://github.com/sahandghavidel/mern-estate/blob/main/package.json), and here is the working project from the tutorial (https://estate.100jsprojects.com/).
My question: The tutorial deploys both the front end and back end to a single URL, but I want to deploy them separately so that the front end has its own URL and the back end has its own URL. I managed to make this work, and here is my working project: (https://real-estate-nms7.onrender.com).
However, I have encountered a problem that only occurs in the production build and not in development mode. When a user goes to the site and clicks "Sign In," the page appears and everything works. But when the user refreshes that page, I get a "Not Found" error. Another issue is that when a user signs in and navigates to a URL like "https://real-estate-nms7.onrender.com/profile" and then refreshes the page, the same "Not Found" error occurs and the cookies disappear. However, when the user navigates back to "https://real-estate-nms7.onrender.com", the cookies reappear and page works.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?
Here is my index.js file:


import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.route.js";
import authRouter from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import listingRouter from "./routes/listing.route.js";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import path from "path";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

console.log("Environment Variables:");
console.log("PORT:", PORT);
console.log("MONGO:", process.env.MONGO);
console.log("JWT_SECERET:", process.env.JWT_SECERET);

// Enable trust proxy
// app.enable("trust proxy", 1);

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://real-estate-nms7.onrender.com"],
    // origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
    methods: ["POST", "GET", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const __dirname = path.resolve();

app.use("/server/user", userRouter);
app.use("/server/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/server/listing", listingRouter);

// Serve static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/dist")));

// The "catchall" handler: for any request that doesn't match one above, send back React's index.html file.
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "dist", "index.html"));
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";
  return res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    statusCode: statusCode,
    message,
  });
});
//l
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`));

// app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
//   res.json({ message: "Hello World" });
// });
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to the Real Estate API");
});



here is my cookies code:


import express from "express";
import User from "../models/user.model.js";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import { errorHandler } from "../utils/error.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
  const newUser = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
  try {
    await newUser.save();

    res.status(201).json("User created successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
    // res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

router.post("/signin", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  console.log("Request Body:", req.body); // Log the request body for debugging

  try {
    const validUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!validUser) return next(errorHandler(404, "User not found!"));
    const validPassword = bcryptjs.compareSync(password, validUser.password);
    if (!validPassword) return next(errorHandler(401, "Wrong credentials!"));

    // Log the JWT secret and token for debugging
    console.log("JWT Secret:", process.env.JWT_SECERET);

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: validUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECERET);
    const { password: pass, ...rest } = validUser._doc;

    res
      .cookie("access_token_voiollamikatahansa", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "None",
        path: "/", 
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(rest);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
    // res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

router.post("/google", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECERET);
      const { password: pass, ...rest } = user._doc;
      res
        .cookie("access_token_voiollamikatahansa", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "None",
          path: "/", 
        })
        .status(200)
        .json({ ...rest, newUser: false });
    } else {
      const generatedPassword =
        Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8) +
        Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
      const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(generatedPassword, 10);
      const newUser = new User({
        username:
          req.body.name.split(" ").join("").toLowerCase() +
          Math.random().toString(36).slice(-4),
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        avatar: req.body.photo,
      });
      await newUser.save();
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: newUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECERET);
      const { password: pass, ...rest } = newUser._doc;
      res
        .cookie("access_token_voiollamikatahansa", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "None",
          path: "/",
        })
        .status(200)
        .json({ ...rest, newUser: true });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

router.get("/signout", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.clearCookie("access_token_voiollamikatahansa");
    res.status(200).json("User has been logged out!");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

export default router;




any advice/help is appreciated

any advice/help is appreciated
